# Python - Selenium - print html content after using find elements by xpath

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I'm testing on the webscrape script and want to verify the html content after `find_elements_by_xpath`, how can it be done?

Here is the script:

```
level1=chromedrv.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='content']/article/div/div[1]/div[1]/div")
for a in level1:
    level2=a.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'image_wrapper')]")
    print (level2)
```

and the output looks like this:

> [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement
> (session="bb0373bdb836fb933150468ad4d66759",
> element="079ea840-cc49-4a7d-8dba-444d61bd996a")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement
> (session="bb0373bdb836fb933150468ad4d66759",
> element="6b49cfaf-7d30-4d95-bc47-05693bc28034")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement
> (session="bb0373bdb836fb933150468ad4d66759",
> element="e91b3497-e1cd-4a7c-a72c-cacc26385d2f")>....

How can I print the html code so I can compare with the webpage inspection?

Thanks

JC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop the level2 list and print it.

```
for level in level2: 
    print (level.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all for a complete answer you have to show all your script, but you can try this:

```
print(driver.page_source)
```

Comment: it returns "list object has no attribute 'page_source'".